# What is this black thing inside LEDs?

Tags: led

I found a bunch of axial red LEDs that have something black inside them. They work fine, they are not burned.

[image: Black inside LED]

I also have some yellow ones with the same black material, for which I was lucky enough to have a [datasheet.](https://docs.rs-online.com/6c03/0900766b8132b640.pdf)

[image: yellow leds with black material]

Not all type of LEDs have this black material inside them. What is this, and what difference does it make to the LED's specifications?

Comment: Anything not red inside red transparent plastic will look black.

Comment: Do the red LEDs also blink?

Comment: @JRE yes they both do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I think it was silly to ask, The datasheet of the yellow LED says "with build-in IC for blinking" So this is it!

[image: blinking led]

Comment: Look inside an RGB colors-changing LED to see its black tiny little IC.